R Studio Install
I received this notification:

R is taking longer to start than usual.

I don't know it could result in my PC (Windows 10) what can I do complete installation or download (Rstudio for Windows I download from original website)?
I don't have any knowledge about any programming. I try to install R 4.4.1 and R

is it launching at all, or just takes longer than anticipated? Is this on first launch, or always?
